# How to load database from SQLite DB file?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to create an SQLite file that will contain the database I will be using in my android app. I need to load it every time I start the app.
An advice on how to do so would be very much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry. To be more specific, I basically just need to know how to address the file in my app's directory, in order to start querying from it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, maybe look at [this.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database

Comment: @fToro Exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you!